# use of regular expression in build.xml

Tags: regex, ant, jenkins

Iam using Jenkins to build my Android Apk. In build.xml, iam using regular expression to replace the my target string as follows...

```
<replaceregexp file="BuildConfig.java" 
     match="public static final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED     =\"(.*)\"" 
     replace="public static final boolean   IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED  =\"" + ${properties.IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED} + "\""  />
```

but when iam running the build through jenkins getting the following error.

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ace Build/build.xml:40: The following error occurred while executing   this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ace Build/IgnitorACE/build.xml:70: Element type "replaceregexp" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Is there any problem with my regular expression...

Thanks

Comment: what is the input and expected output

Comment: I have build.xml where i will have public statc final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED = false/true variable declared. I have properties file through which i will pass the above boolean value during runtime. For this reason iam using the above regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting seems to be because of the quotes (`"`). You should use `&quot;` instead. Below example works:

BuildConfig.java:

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String []args) {
       public static final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED = false
       System.out.println("Hello World");      
    }
}
```

file.properties:

```
IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED=true
```

build.xml:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="regextask" basedir=".">
  <property file="file.properties"/>

  <target name="regextask">
        <replaceregexp  file="BuildConfig.java" 
                        match="public static final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED = (.*)" 
                        replace="public static final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED = &quot;${IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED}&quot;" 
        />    
  </target>
</project>
```

[image]

Output:

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String []args) {
       public static final boolean IS_SAMSUNG_MDM_ENABLED = "true"
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Technext... I have three properties files like A.properties, B.properties and C.properties files in my SVN. Iam using fileparameter in jenkins. So, when ever i upload particular property file then that properties should be reflected in the code. Can you help me out